# Markov Chain Problem

Tags: probability, random-walk

I have been stuck on this question for days and really need some help.

There are two methods, A and B, to finish a work. Method A succeeds with probability 1/3, but if it fails one tries method B with probability 3/4 or method A again with probability 1/4. Method B succeeds with probability 1/4, but if it fails one tries method A with probability 2/3 or method B again with probability 1/3. Successive choices are made according to the scheme above until success. What is the probability that success will be made by method A if
a) one starts with method A?
b) one starts with method B?

I believe the problem is dealing with a random walk event..but there are differing probabilities based on success or failure.

I also understand that I should be using the equation:

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!